# Retrieving the ID/GUID for a DOM element

Tags: jquery, dom, guid

Assume I have the following DOM structure in a webpage

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="id1">Hello, this is div 1</div>
        <div>This is div 2</div>
        <div>And, this is div 3</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the first `div` has an `id` of **id1**, yet the second `div` and third `div` do not have any.

Typically, in jQuery, you can do the following selections

```
$("#id") // <-------------- Selector for the first div
$("div") // <-------------- Selector for all three div's
```

So, from a UI perspective, we can select the first `div` by **id**, and all three `div`'s by an element selector.

However, I am sure that each DOM elements will have an **internal DOM id** that is used to distinguish each element from all others. For example, all three `div`'s will have some sort of **guid** or something similar, maybe 1, 2, and 3 (in other words, I would like the ID for the **this** element for each div, and I am assuming it is unique per page.

How can I get that ID? I would like to access this ID via jQuery if possible.

PS. I tried using jQuery events to get access that information, but no luck yet. I will read more about it, but you may also know the answer better than me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"However, I am sure that each DOM elements will have an internal DOM id that is used to distinguish each element from all others."*

There are no internal DOM IDs and even if there were they'd be just that, internal, and not accessible to you. You could use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and then you could refer to the index of the element in the collection you wanted.

For example in vanilla JavaScript you could do:

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var secondDiv = foo[1];
```

Or in jQuery you could do:

```
$('div').eq(1) // or $('div:eq(1)')
```